# Django, jquery.formset and Select2 issues

Tags: javascript, django, jquery-select2

Using Django 1.6, [django-select2](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2) (latest) and [jquery.formset.js](https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset) (latest), I'm struggling with something that should be quite simple. Essentially when I use the add formset capability provided by jquery.formset.js the new formset is missing the select field provided by django-select2, although the rest of the formset renders fine.

It's a fairly basic set up:

```
class PartNumber(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Description", max_length=100)
    supplier_part_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)

class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    po_number = models.CharField('PO number', max_length=10, unique=True)
    ordered_date = models.DateField(default=today)

class PurchaseOrderPart(models.Model):
    part_number = models.ForeignKey(PartNumber, related_name='purchases')
    po_number = models.ForeignKey(PurchaseOrder, related_name='partslist')
    delivery_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    qty_ordered = models.IntegerField('Quantity ordered',validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    cost = models.DecimalField('Unit Cost', max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,blank=True,null=True)
```

I have the create view of a PurchaseOrder having PurchaseOrderParts as an inline_formset:

```
class PurchaseOrderPartForm(forms.ModelForm):
    part_numbers = PartNumberChoices()
    class Meta:
      fields = ('part_numbers', 'delivery_date', 'qty_ordered', 'cost')
      model = PurchaseOrderPart
      widgets={
        'part_numbers': forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'delivery_date': CalendarWidget(attrs={'class':'input-append form-control'}),
        'qty_ordered': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'cost': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }

POPartFormset = inlineformset_factory(PurchaseOrder, PurchaseOrderPart, form=PurchaseOrderPartForm, extra=1, can_delete=True)
```

And I'm using jquery.formset.js so that there are "add" and "remove" buttons on the PurchaseOrder create view, so that any number of PurchaseOrderParts might be added (any one PO might have from 1 to infinite parts attached, in reality more likely to be < 10).

That was working fine.

But the PartNumber fk on a PurchaseOrderPart has a huge list (~2500 items) so the select list is inconvenient.

I installed django-select2 and was pretty impressed at how easily it was to get running:

```
class PurchaseOrderPartForm(forms.ModelForm):
    part_numbers = PartNumberChoices()
    class Meta:
      fields = ('part_numbers', 'delivery_date', 'qty_ordered', 'cost')
      model = PurchaseOrderPart
      widgets={
        'part_numbers': django_select2.AutoHeavySelect2Widget(),
        'delivery_date': CalendarWidget(attrs={'class':'input-append form-control'}),
        'qty_ordered': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        'cost': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

This is when we have problems. It all works until you use the jquery.formset.js to add a new formset - it renders perfectly but fails to include the django-select2 select.

In particular, the new formset is missing this code:

```
<div class="select2-container select2-container-active" id="s2id_id_partslist-1-part_numbers"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen">&nbsp;</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow"><b></b></span></a><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" id="s2id_autogen5"></div>
```

How might I go about force inserting the select2-container?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug of django-select2 that has been fixed in a very recent merge. 
When you are saying that you are running the latest version, do you mean from github or from PIP ?

Either way, you might be interrested in this:
https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2/pull/127

Comment: now that I look at it, I am using django-select2 - but from pypi, so version 4.2.2. When do you think pypi will be updated? Thanks for the work thus far.

Comment: @datakid, I would suggest you subscribe to the github of django-select2. Thers is already another person who requested a new release. See: https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2/issues/116